# Standard user cannot change password

Tags: macos, password

On my macbook, running OSX Mavericks, my daughter has a standard-user account.

I wanted to show her how to change her login password under:

**SystemPreferences > Users & Groups > ChangePassword**

That button was greyed out, even after the padlock was opened.

Note: she is under parental control, but even after I temporarily lifted that, changing the password was not possible.

---

**Any ideas, on how to allow my daughter to change her login password?**

Comment: After you removed parental control, did she log out and in again?

Comment: @patrix No, she didn't.

Comment: Might be worth a try then (disable control, have her log out/in again and then change password)

Comment: Is the change of a user password prohibited when the user is under parental control?

Comment: Nope, but that part you figured out already. But AFAIK you need to log out/in if you switch an account from/to parental control

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just figured out what was wrong. I had actually disabled my daughter to change her password under parental control (ages ago when I've set it up). To undo that I had to

**SystemPreferences > ParentialControls > Other**

where I could untick the box "Disable changing the password".